# Populate a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

The problem I have with `ListView` is that only the ListView is scrollable and not the whole screen.

For example, if I have a layout like the one below, only the ListView part of the screen is scrollable, whereas I want the whole screen to scroll:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, World!"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum."
            />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to populate a `LinearLayout`, like the one above, in order to make the whole screen scrollable?

Comment: In that case you probably don't want ListView. Just add contents of listview - i dont know what you have in there, maybe textviews or so - dynamically into your linearlayout which should be inside scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to handle this, ListView provides a `addHeaderView(View)` method so you can do this:

Create a header_layout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, World!"/>

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum."/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

then have your main_activity.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
         android:paddingLeft="24dp"
         android:paddingRight="24dp"
         android:paddingTop="24dp"
         android:paddingBottom="24dp"> 
       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
     </FrameLayout>
```

Then in your MainActivity.java

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity{

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

                // reference your list
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                // Inflate the header and add the view
                View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.header_view, null);
                listView.addHeaderView(headerView);

            }
     }
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. 
Easy way - Wrap everything in `ScrollView` its ugly, not recommended but could work.

**Much better way** - `ListView` has `addHeaderView(View v)` and `addFooterView(View v)` If you want to have something above use header and if you want something below just use footer. In your case take these two `TextViews` to new layout file. Inflate it like here

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_created_layout_with_these_two_text_views,null)
```

and add created view as header.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with what you are trying to do

1) You cannot scroll a `LinearLayout`. In order to scroll a `LinearLayout`, you must insert a `ScrollView` as its first and only child, then put all your child views inside the `ScrollView`

2) What you are trying to do will not work.  `ScrollView` and `ListView` are just a window into the content. The actual `ListView` itself is only as large as the space it occupies on screen, rather than the size of the content contained within it.  If you want the content of the `ListView` and the `TextView`'s to scroll together, you should either add the `TextView`'s into the `ListView`, or add a wrapping view as the `ListView`'s header view.  Your other option is to not use a `ListView` at all, and just append all children to your `ScrollView` programatically.

Note: You should not use a `ScrollView` AND a `ListView`.  Pick one approach and stick to it.